# Calculate delay in long line

Tags: resistors, wire

Assume we are connecting a lamp to a source but line (wire) is so long (for example 20Km):

Will the lamp bright after connecting the source immediately?

how much time it will be?

Can we calculate this delay?

Can the AC or DC source effects on this delay?

The resistance of the wire will increase with increasing the length of the wire, What relation is there between the length of the wire and the resistance?

is there this delay when transmittal of  any resistor in the circuit?(if resistance of resistor be equal resistance of the long wire)

Comment: I cannot understand the last question.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Hi,This is not a homework question.maybe I dont bring up my question well.I dont find the answer of these question in link below.

Comment: @musefian Please use "@" symbol when you want to refere to a guy. like me that refered to you.

Answer (score 1):

Propagation delay in copper wire was answered here: [Speed of electricity (signal propagation?) through copper for communications delay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45492/speed-of-electricity-signal-propagation-through-copper-for-communications-del)

This is for CAT5 cable. The resistance will depend on the gauge "thickness" of the conductor"

[This chart shows resistance of copper wire by gauge per foot](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-wire-d_1429.html)