# How much difference in net length is ok?

Tags: signal, bus, omap, length-matching

Sorry, but I couldn't find a better title. Consider the following: I have an address/data bus interface. Intended frequency of the D/A bus would be around 10-50MHz.

According to the [datasheet of the device in question](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/omap-l138.pdf) (OMAP-L138) the maximum clock frequency appears to be around 100MHz (tCLK(min) is specified as 10ns). I would **guess** that the rise time of the signals would be around 200ps. But this is really just a guess since I wasn't able to get the information from said manual.

Now I was wondering if there was a rule of thumb of how much (length) the traces may differ, e.g. how much A1 may be offset from A2.

Comment: As much as you want, provided setup and hold times are followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more precise terms to use are *setup time* and *hold time*, since your clocking scheme may vary. That is, your signals may be sampled on both edges (DDR), and so on.

From what I understand, *setup time* is for how long your data needs to be stable **before** a sampling clock edge and *hold time* is **after** your clock edge.

---

With a falling-setup and rising-sample scheme you practically make both these times \$T/2\$. Given your clock frequency of \$50MHz\$, the period \$T = \frac{1}{50\times10^6} = 20ns\$, thus \$T/2 = 10ns\$.

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45492/speed-of-electricity-signal-propagation-through-copper-for-communications-del) the worst case propagation speed through copper is \$5.3 ns/m\$. Plugging this into the thing gives you \$\tilde{}1.9m\$. This if of course totally wrong, thus I must have wronged something. Someone please correct me.

Comment: 50MHz is a low enough frequency that 1.9m is a perfectly reasonable result. But the actual impedance of the trace will make the real number quite a bit lower.

Comment: @Dzarda: That seems like a quite large number to me as well. My signal is only a single-sampled signal (only on one edge). The current trace length is around 60mm, with traces going +/- 5mm. I would guess there need to be other restrictions.

Comment: @Ignacio: Could you elaborate on that a little?

Answer (score 0):

The key factor depends on the skew and sample and hold time. If it is about 200ps (and Er = 4.5):

\$v = c/{\sqrt(E_r)} = 141.323.520m/s ≈ 141\mu m/ps\$

\$TraceLength_{Max} = v(\mu m/ps)·skew_{Max}(ps) ≈ 28264\mu m = 28.264mm\$